# Pytest won't import folders correctly

Tags: pytest, directory-structure

I am trying to write unit tests using pytest for a file. My directory structure looks like this:

```
--app
    --app.py
    --src
        --helpers
            --math
                --__init__.py
                --file1.py
                --file2.py

    --tests
        --unit
            --test_file1.py
        --functional
    --conftest.py
```

In test_file1.py, I have the followimg import statement:
from src.helpers.math.file1 import mainClass

When I call pytest on test_file1.py, it insists ModuleNotFoundError: No module named helpers. I don't understand why it can't find helpers.

I have tried adding an `__init__.py` file to src and helpers; I've tried changing how I call the import statement to only say src,helpers.math and other combinations; but no matter what I do, pytest can't seem to find this module and I don't understand why. Another pytest file that is testing a file with only functions, no classes, is working fine so I'm convinced I'm doing something wrong with classes.

Comment: Fix your post, the directory structure looks broken. But This can help you: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/pythonpath.html

Comment: Hi Cassidy. Usually, we put conftest.py inside the test folder.

Comment: Also, if you have a src file, maybe you want to create a package with a config file such as pyproject.toml? If that so, the answer from Karine Bauch will work after installing your project using `pip install -e .` (`__init__.py` in helpers will be required) (https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/). If that's what you are looking for, you may want to move all your sources in the src folder (I don't know what is app, but if that the entry point of your package, you may want it included in the sources.)